# quarkus websocket is not working properly at azure webapp

Tags: azure-web-app-service, quarkus, java-websocket

## Issue

Websocket is closed once it receive a message at the client side (browser).

## Actual behavior

On the 3rd message I send, I can see the error message at the console that WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
[image]

## How to Reproduce?

1. git clone https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts.git
2. cd websockets-quickstart
3. edit index.html at line 81 from 'ws' to 'wss'
4. add application.properties under src/main/resources
5. add 'quarkus.http.port=80' to application.properties
6. add 'quarkus.package.type=uber-jar' to application.properties
7. configure azure webapp plugin by executing: mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.3.0:config
8. choose (linux, java 11)
9. mvn package azure-webapp:deploy
10. navigate to the deployed app

## Deployed App

https://quarkus-websockets-quickstart.azurewebsites.net/

## Additional Info

I managed to deploy to Azure Webapp with the same configuration as above a spring implementation with sockjs. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/using-websocket-with-java-in-azure-app-service/ba-p/3158851
This is working. Deployed version: https://spring-messaging-stomp-websocket.azurewebsites.net/

What am I missing? -.-

Comment: Can you implement `socket.onClose and socket.onError`.  Perhaps they might give you helpful information

Comment: I did add `onClose` at the backend:

```2022-06-11T16:32:49.541513976Z: [INFO]  2022-06-11 16:32:49,541 INFO  [org.acm.web.ChatSocket] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) Closing session u9cSze3niJuiG6xKecOrZ-zs_6nrPv3cOL5KFWPX for user daniel

2022-06-11T16:32:49.542790949Z: [INFO]  2022-06-11 16:32:49,541 INFO  [org.acm.web.ChatSocket] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) CloseReason:  Code: (GOING_AWAY)```

Comment: It seems to be something related to Azure's webserver because I deployed it to a private server outside Azure and it's working.

Comment: Maybe azure requires some heartbeat functionality that springboot provides?  If azure sees the pings it is not killing the connection with springboot??

Comment: Guessing that's something with TLS/SSL since the app will listen to port 80. WS default port is 80 but WSS is 443. Azure will listen on both, but the app only on 80.